# Why `console.log` doesn't work inside button (click)?

Tags: angular, typescript

Why this doesn't work?

```html
<button (click)="console.log('ok');">Display Detais</button>
```

It says

```js
Cannot read property 'log' of undefined
```

but a `console.log` in the class constructor works:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app3-directives',
  templateUrl: './directives.component.html'
})
export class DirectivesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { console.log('start') }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

...the 'start' does prints in the console. So why in the button it is undefined?

Comment: Are you really going to *Display Details* using `console.log` in such a manner?

Comment: @R.Richards nope... I just want to understand how angular works, the explanation for this may help me with some other thing in a important moment when I have no time to study.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `console` object is unknown in the template since it is not a public property of the component. What you could do:

```js
export class DirectivesComponent implements OnInit {

  // console is now known inside the template
  console = console;

  constructor() { console.log('start') }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

However, I do not recommend this way for logging purposes. Logging should be for development only, therefore keep it in the component. Maybe something like:

```js
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';

...

click() {
  if (isDevMode()) {
    console.log('do some logging');
  }
}
```